# Redux, ensure that call is performed after redux completes

Tags: reactjs, redux

I make a call to one of my redux actions like this:

```
performAction(updatesomevalue);
```

and I want to send my state somewhere when the above action is finished:

```
sendState(state);
```

how do I chain those calls? actions does not have callbacks, so I cannot use that approach, and I guess that might not be such a reduxy way of doing it anyway?

Comment: A simple way that should work is to add it to the JS event queue via a `setTimeout` call within the redux action handling code. I've done this a lot, when I needed side-effects, however if you modify the state in `sendState` (outside of the redux flow) you're probably going to have a bad time.

Comment: If you mean the code that is calling `performAction` needs to pass in a callback, and it is going to use the result, then I would say IMHO you should try to move whatever would be done in that callback into the event flow/redux state instead, to remove the need for that callback. I have done this, too (promises and callbacks from actions), but it is more fragile and harder to reason about, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

**Async Redux Actions with redux-thunk**

The simplest solution when dealing with asynchronous Redux actions is to use redux-thunk.

The purpose of redux-thunk is that it allows us to dispatch functions as actions (as opposed to regular old objects that you are probably used to)

**Why would we want to dispatch actions that return a function?**

This question could be rephrased as - Why is redux-thunk a useful library?

If we can dispatch a function. Then this function can be given access to the the redux store api, therefore when the action is called in the future it has access to the store's current state and dispatch. Having access to dispatch is critical as it means that this function can dispatch additional redux actions. Here is an example of a redux thunk action creator that follows the redux-thunk signature of returning a function.

This redux thunk action creator dispatches an initial  asynchronous action such as calling an external api and then updating state with the result of that async api call.

Then the new state is retrieved and used to dispatch an additional action.
To make the first async api cal we are using the isomorphic-fetch library which is a promise based request library, this is why we are able to chain fetch with .then as calling fetch returns a thenable promise.

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

// call api then update state and dispatch second sync action
// based on new state
function thunkActionCreator () {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    return fetch(`http://www.example.com/api/users/${id}`)
            .then(response => {
              // if request successful dispatch action
              // using response data to change state
              if (response.status !== 200) {
                dispatch(firstAction(response.data))
              }

              // get the new state
              const secondState = getState()

              // use this newState to dispatch a new action
              dispatch(secondAction(secondState))
            })
  }
}
```

**Remember you need to add redux-thunk to the middleware chain**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

Since redux-thunk is a piece of middleware it sits in the middleware chain. When an action is dispatched in any redux application it goes through the complete middleware chain and each piece of middleware implements some custom functionality such as logging in the case of redux-logger which console.logs out actions as they occur in your application.